# Thinking Recursively when it comes to list manipulation

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.4

```
from random import *

def Number(N):
    if N>0:
        return [ choice( [0,1] ) for i in range(N)]
    else:
        return ("Only Positive #'s!")
```

How would I do this recursively?

Let's say `N=5`, so `[0,1,2,3,4]` for each # to be replaced with either a `0` or a `1`. I just can't seem to wrap my head around doing this list manipulation recursively.

Comment: So your advice is I should stick with that bit of code I wrote and consider it the only logical way to do it. I was hoping to avoid using a loop/iteration.

Comment: @Xuvin you could rewrite it recursively, but it's not clear why you'd want to. What's the problem with an iterative implementation?

Comment: Are you asking just out of curiousity?  It's not obvious that this specific problem would benefit from a recursive solution; I can't see that it would be clearer or perform better.

Comment: @jonrsharpe @ Rory Yorke It's an assignment recursion being the tool of use. But elsewhere in the sample code given iteration was used... so I am having issues finding examples where this kind of list manipulation can happen recursively. Thank you very much JonrSharpe for your answer below! It's exactly what I needed to understand and more!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
from random import choice  # don't use * imports

def Number_recursive(N):
    if N < 0:
        raise ValueError('N must be positive')
    if N == 0:
        return []
    return [choice((0, 1))] + Number_recursive(N-1)
```

Note the raising of an error rather than returning a string; this tells the caller more directly that something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how recursion will help here. How about just simplifying it like this:

```
from random import choice

def binary_list(length):
    return [choice([0, 1]) for x in range(0, length)]
```

Comment: It may help if it's an exercise about using recursion :-)

Comment: @6502 Ya, someone had asked OP about that, but so far no response.

Comment: Yea just answered! Sorry still fiddling with it, it is an assignment, thanks so much for your posts all.

Comment: @Xuvin Ah, OK. Ya, jonrsharpe's answer is nice!